# Is it possible on iOS to use the hardware encryption with the device key and an app specific passcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, hardware

We would like to assign the app specific passcode (not the device passcode) to the hardware encryption unit on the iOS devices to encrypt certain files. This would make brute force attacs to those files harder since the unknown devicekey could be used to derive the actual encryption key.

Is that possible on iOS?

thanx

jom123

Comment: Hey jom, we would also would like to do the exact same thing in our current app. Did you end up finding a way to do this? If not, what approach did you end up taking?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do encryption of your App's data, your best bet is to use the Common Crypto library provided with iOS.  You don't have access to the "hardware encryption unit".

There's a sample you can download & run at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008019-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2  Take a look at "- (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)plainText key:(NSData *)symmetricKey context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt padding:(CCOptions *)pkcs7" inside SecKeyWrapper.m -- this is the "encrypt/decrypt" meat of the application.  There is documentation on the library available here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html

Be aware there are export restrictions with providing encryption in your application and you may need a CCATS form.

Comment: Thank you, I'm familiar with these techniques and I know that hardware acceleration for encryption is automatically used if the data to encrypt is large enough.

Comment: It would be a significant advantage if the unknown hardware device key would be used as a salt to derive the encryption key. To achieve this it wouldn't be necessary to extract the devicekey. The hardware should do the key derivation and the encryption. Is this functionality already abvailable?

Comment: use the MAC address as a salt (yes I know it can be faked)

Answer (score 0):

See : [Working with Protected Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4)

Comment: The protected files mechanism uses the passcode to unlock the device is used to encrypt the files. We want to use another password (entered in our app) together with the devicekey to encrypt the files.